# Change Call Settings Programmatically

Tags: android, settings

I understand that it is currently possible to change Android system settings via the [Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) class and its `putString()` method.

However, the setting I wish to change programmatically (Text message reply under Call settings and call forwarding) is not in this class.

How would I go about modifying call settings? Is there as class similar to Settings.System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe "Text message reply" setting in Call settings is customized. 
I have checked 2.2, 2.3, 4.0 versions. This option is not available in original Call settings. This must be from your device manufacturers side.

So if you know the string name and its possible values, you can change it.